# Spline bezier interpolation

Tags: graphics, interpolation, linear-algebra, spline, bezier

How to interpolate a given set of *n* points, and its derivatives, using a Bezier spline?

Currently I'm using a library (SDL_gfx) which has a function, [bezierRGBA()](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/_s_d_l__gfx_primitives_8h.html#a7203e3a463da499b5b0cadf211d19ff3), that draws a Bezier curve given its control points.

I have searched on the web, but it isn't clear to me how to get the bezier control points from a given set of points, and its derivatives.

Comment: what do you mean bezier control points from a given set of points? If you want to have a bezier curve you need to know its control points.

Comment: Can't the control points be determined by the tangents? The points in the case are known **positions** of a body over time. I was hoping to draw a estimated trajectory using consecutive Bezier curves. The velocity of the body (first derivative) is available for each point.

Comment: Bezier curves don't interpolate the points except the first and the last one... If you want to interpolate, you can use Catmull-Rom for example...You can fit a Bezier curve to a set of points though... That happens by solving a least square system for finding the control points... That can be formed for the trajectories or actual points...

Comment: @GoodLuck Bezier curves most certainly interpolate between all points, it's the only curve that is literally a nested linear interpolation between any N given points, thus always rendering inside the hull defined by those points, and mapping 1:1 to the Bernstein polynomial defined by those points.

Comment: @hydren what do you actually need to know, though. Do you have points that you want to join up? Because then why use Bezier curves instead of better candidates? (like Catmull-Rom curves or another cardinal spline)

Comment: When you say interpolation this means that the curve should go through the control points that does not happen for bezier. What you are saying is another property of the curves called convex hull. These are simple terminologies in computer graphics.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the position vector and first derivative vector at each point, you can easily create a cubic Bezier curve in between two consecutive points. Denoting the two points as P0 and P1 and the first derivatives as P'0 and P'1, then the cubic Bezier curve's control points Qi (i=0~3) can be found as

```
Q0=P0
Q1=P'0/3 + P0
Q2=P1-P'1/3
Q3=P1
```

Repeat this process for each two consecutive points (and first derivatives) of your data points and you will get a series of cubic Bezier curves that are connected in a C1 manner.

Comment: Thanks fang, with your equations the resulting curve worked and indeed had C1 parametric continuity, but it was rather too oscillating. Do you know any equations to fetch control points for a **quadratic** bezier curve? I think it should fit better the trajectory shape.

Comment: If the curve oscillates too much, it is typically because of the magnitude of the first derivatives are being too large. If you what you know is not the actual first derivative vectors but the tangent vectors only (i.e., the magnitude is really undecided), there is a good way to decide "good" magnitudes to reduce oscillations.

Comment: You do not always be able to decide a quadratic Bezier curve from two points and two first derivatives, for example, when the two first derivatives are parallel to each other but not to the line defined by the two end points.

Answer (score 1):

In a Bezier curve, you have a set of control points `P` that are multiplied in Bernstein polynomials that are defined on the parameter `u`. A point on the Bezier curve is Q(u)=sum (i from 0 to d) Pi*Bi,d in which d is the number of control points and determine the degree too. You can check my website: http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~amahdavi/pmwiki-2.2.8/uploads/Site/last1.pdf to see the actual formula. You can find the formula for the tangent and an efficient way to implement Bezier Curves as well (de Casteljau algorithm)

Comment: this is kind of a bad explanation. http://cubic-bezier.com/, https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier, and https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo are far better places to send people.

Comment: This is a university website that I am certain about its content. If you have a better answer you can send it as another answer here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I read your website. It is quite interesting. You should send yours as an answer too so it would be available to others. About the interpolation comment, as you know Bezier curves are the result of linear interpolation of control points. However, they do not interpolate their control points. Therefore, they are not interpolating. Therefore, if you have a set of points to be interpolated, if you take them as your control points, your bezier curve does not go through them which is the case of this question (I believe). Take a look at my website and let me know what youthink

Comment: Indeed, a bezier curve does not necessarily interpolate its control points. Actually, in most of the cases it won't. What I'm searching for is a method to obtain a set of control points from which the resulting curve would interpolate a specific pair of points. And also use the said method for each two consecutive points from a specific data set, keeping at least a C1 parametric continuity.

Comment: I kept researching the subject, and I found out about the [Catmull–Rom spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Catmull.E2.80.93Rom_spline).

Comment: @Hydren I already told you the possibility of using Catmull-Rom in my comments: "Bezier curves don't interpolate the points except the first and the last one... If you want to interpolate, you can use Catmull-Rom for example...."

Comment: @GoodLuck I think you misunderstood the question. You can easily compute the control points of a cubic Bezier passing through four consecutive points. This has been [shown and explained by Burkardt](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225210855/http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/html/bezier_interpolation.html). Fang's answer points to the same approach ("_the thirds_") but I find Burkardt's explanation easier.